# Import GetStdHandle function from kernel32.dll in assembly

Tags: assembly, dll, import, reference, undefined

I have proble with import GetStdHandle function from kernel32.dll, when i try to link my app i receive that error:

```
winapiwrite.obj:winapiwrite.asm:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `GetStdHandle@4'
```

my app code:

```
;winapiwrite.asm
;
;Command line
;nasm -f win32 winapiwrite.asm
;ld winapiwrite.obj -o winapiwrite.exe c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll

[bits 32]
extern _ExitProcess@4
extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _WriteConsoleA@20
global _WinMain@16

section .data
str_hello:
  db "Hello world!", 0  ;length = 12bytes

section .text
_WinMain@16:
  ;stack frame
  push ebp
  sub esp, 4

  ;GetStdHandle( -11 ): stdoutput
  push -11
  call _GetStdHandle@4
  mov ebx, eax

  ;WriteConsoleA( Output, &text, len, &bytes, reserved ) 
  push 0
  lea eax, [ebp-4]
  push eax
  push 12
  push str_hello
  push ebx
  call _WriteConsoleA@20

  ;ExitProcess( 0 )
  push 0
  call _ExitProcess@4
;END OF _WinMain@16
```

additional when i change name of function in code from:

```
_GetStdHandle@4
```

to:

```
_GetStdHandle
```

i receive that error:

```
ertr000006.o:(.rdata+0x0): undefined reference to `_pei386_runtime_relocator'
```

I'm don't know what ExitProcess and WriteConsoleA import with no problem and with GetStdHandle are problems, I'm thinking about that from hours and I haven't any solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No problems here at all with MinGW and Cygwin. Maybe there is a typo in your source, e.g. a strange character which is not shown in the text editor.

Comment: Thanks, there was problem with lib on my compuetr, I downloaded another kernel32.lib and was no linker problems with it

Answer (score 3):

[SOLUTION]

There is something wrong with kernel32.lib in my computer. I downloaded another kernel32.lib and with it was no linker problem.